# How do I convert world data into a map and how do I install server side mods?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, server-administration

I have a couple questions. I'm hosting a Minecraft server that I downloaded directly from the minecraft.net site. It's legit and whatnot.

First of all I was wondering if there was a map app that could take the world data and convert it into a map on the server side (not the client mods), hopefully one that's live and runs in a browser.

Secondly, is it possible to put the vanilla minecraft server 1.0 into something like bukkit so I can install server-side mods? If so where would I go and how would I get started.

Comment: Just a clarification: Bukkit is a replacement for the vanilla server, not an addon. Vanilla clients can connect just fine however.

Comment: Well it's not it's own software, it needs the real server to run, it just modifies it.

Comment: If you download Bukkit you will get a fully functional Minecraft server. It's true that they extend the vanilla server, it's not a full reimplementation, but as a project it's a replacement not an addon; ie. you don't need a copy of the vanilla server to use it.

Comment: For the most part, a vanilla world should work fine in Bukkit, but the reverse probably isn't true, especially if you start using server mods.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming SE @kelton52!  The Stack Exchange Q&A format works best when each question contains a single question.  If you have multiple questions, feel free to make each one a separate question.  That way, you will know when each question is answered and you can accept the best answer for each one.

Comment: Yeah I was going to, but I kind of assumed the answer to the first question would hing on the possibility of the second. I'll split them up next time though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bukkit is a standalone replacement for minecraft_server.jar and if you want server-side plugins you need to use it. While there isn't a stable release for Minecraft 1.0, after some trial and error I found that [build 1493](http://ci.bukkit.org/job/dev-CraftBukkit/1493/) works and has been running my Minecraft 1.0 world successfully for a few days now.

I can't help you setup Bukkit standalone because I never did that - I installed [McMyAdmin](http://www.mcmyadmin.com/). Set it up according to the install directions, go into the control panel and select "Update/Install Bukkit" under About/Updates. It will warn about downgrading - that's OK. Once it has installed bukkit, open the MCMA\Minecraft folder and replace the craftbukkit.jar with build 1493 from the above link. Copy your world in and adjust the server.properties file as needed.

In theory, if you have a working minecraft_server.jar setup running you could just change it to point to craftbukkit.jar.

As for dynamic mapping, the plugin you want is [Dynmap](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/dynmap/).

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. I'll give it a shot and let you know. I heard of mcmyadmin, that would be nice to admin the server via the browser.

Comment: I can't believe this worked so well. This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you @kelton52